# RAD Studio ADO Data Set slow loading data

Tags: c++, dataset, ado, c++builder

I have a Windows application written in RAD studio c++. The application uses an ADO Connection and ADO Data Sets. Loading the Data Set's data over the local network is fast enough, but once the user connects through the internet the speed loading the ado data set is extremely slow. The database is `SQL Server 2012 express` and the specific table (Customers) has 9 000 records with (8 columns) which is called with `SELECT * FROM Customers`.

I use `ADODataSet->Active = true;` to open the data source.

Is there any settings which I can set on the data set to speed it up ? any other advise to increase the speed when activating the data source ?

Comment: While I don't know anything about ADO or the RAD Studios ADO classes, just 9000 records from a single table should be very quick, unless each record contains a lot of large BLOBs. A common method to make things quicker otherwise is local caching.

Comment: I have considered local caching, it will require allot of code though since the data can change daily. What would you suggest as the best method a caching a local table ?

Answer (score 1):

You'll be pushing a bunch of bytes across the intenet:  9,000 records of, say, 220 bytes each is a non-trivial amount of data--a couple of megabytes.   ADO.NET is a reasonably efficient protocol, so unless you want to change your architecture, the best advice I can give is:

1. Don't use `SELECT *` unless you need all columns
2. Make sure you're not going through a router that has a low packet
   fragmentation limit.
3. You can page your query, so that the visible part of the UI is populated
   quickly:  this won't reduce the query time (in fact, it will
   increase it somewhat), but it will reduce the *subjective* time to
   the user (since he's not just staring at a blank screen)
4. You can use "lazy loading" techniques:  return only the rows that are displayed in the selection grid (or tree, or whatever).   Don't download full records until you have to display detail, and then cache them once you've got them.

Comment: Thanks, number 4 would probably work best if I can get it any quicker. Although it would require a substantial amount of code changes.